# Função para permitir apenas um voto por equipamento

Tags: php, mysql

Montei um sistema simples de enquete no qual é possível votar apenas um vez por IP. No entanto, ele registra o IP da rede e não do computador do usuário, impossibilitando que outros equipamentos na mesma rede possam votar.
Já pesquisei no Google e não achei nenhuma alternativa para sanar este problema. Gostaria da sugestão de vocês.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646690/how-to-get-real-ip-from-visitor Resposta daqui no stackoverflow

Comment: É impossível identificar a "maquina do usuário", independente de linguagem que rode no teu servidor.

Comment: @WeesSmith isso ai é pra tentar resolver problemas com PROXY e não com equipamentos.

Comment: Qual a sugestão de vocês então no sentido de permitir que uma enquete possa ser votada apenas uma vez por computador.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não sabia que era impossivel, então a solução mais adequada seria a utilização de um identificador, como numero de telefone com DDD

Comment: @Eduardo poderia usar um cookie com longo prazo de vida, mas se o usuário limpar os cookies então ele poderá burlar o sistema, não existe solução garantida.

Comment: um, entendi Guilherme, vou dar uma olhada sobre o que eu faço entao.... obrigado a todos.

Comment: Sem contar que o usuário poderá usar outro navegador. Então aquele cookie não será utilizado. É melhor utilizar um identificador(telefone, rg, cpf). Pois mesmo que o usuário não tenha o cookie naquele navegador ele não conseguirá votar duas vezes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**É impossível** diferenciar dois equipamentos que usam uma mesma rede usando somente seu *website*, independente da linguagem de programação que use no seu servidor, ainda sim existem algumas alternativas, como cookies, que no entanto podem ser burlados facilmente se o usuário desejar limpar os dados de navegação, segue sugestões:

### Cookie / localStorage

O máximo que você pode fazer é criar um cookie, ou **"talvez"** `localStorage` do JavaScript, mas não quer dizer que terá garantias contra fraudes nos votos, pois o usuário pode simplesmente apagar os cookies ou o localStorage e pronto, ele poderá votar novamente.

### Votar via aplicativo

Outra solução é criar um app, que irá usar outro tipo de identificação, como o numero de celular da pessoa, claro que os votos só poderiam ser feitos pelo app, então nada de site, somente webservice e um TOKEN para identificação entre cliente e servidor, desta forma ficaria muito mais difícil do usuário burlar.

### Validar o voto

Se deseja mesmo via web uma forma de garantir que o voto seja real é validando via outros meios, como e-mail, por exemplo:

- a pessoa que vota digita o email e seleciona a opção de voto
- o servidor gera um link único que só pode ser usado uma vez
- o servidor envia o link via email para usuário que votou
- o usuário abre a INBOX e clica no link
- ao acessar o link o servidor valida o voto marca com alguma "flag" que o link expirou (pode ser feito tudo via banco de dados)

Essa mesma técnica poderia ser usada com validação via SMS, claro que isto dependerá de um serviço que envie e receba o SMS.

---

### Zombie cookie

A alguns anos alguns sites grandes foram acusados de usar uma técnica chamada `zombie cookie` ou `evercookie` ou `persistent cookie` (tinha outros nomes para isto, se lembrar irei editar), é uma técnica **bastante variante**, que consiste geralmente em criar o cookie e usar outros aspectos como:

- cache
- criar um elemento temporário na página
- ajax
- localStorage / sessionStorage
- tecnologias embarcadas como flash ou silverlight

Ou seja gravava de várias maneiras uma referencia simples que serviria de identificação para regenerar o cookie acaso o usuário limpasse todos dados de navegação, então desde que a página estivesse aberta, mesmo limpando os dados eles eram regenerados, ainda sim usuários mais avançados sabiam bem como burlar isto.

Entenda que não estou falando para fazer o uso disto e nem mesmo irei fornecer um código para isto, só estou comentando pois o assunto parece cabível aqui, já que a técnica foi criada com um proposito semelhante.

Esta técnica apesar de trazer uma razoável eficiência ainda sim tem controvérsias e talvez no Brasil não ocasione nada como processo, ainda sim a técnica já foi acusada de violar a privacidade do usuário, inclusive a própria MicroSoft passou por algo assim por usar um "cookie" para identificar os usuários, o que posteriormente depois da polemica foi desativado.